# APSN Error : Push server

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

The problem I am facing is server side imlementation of the APNS.
Created sample app got token 
Created server php code creater the certificate adn all works in local server perfectly with mamp.[Tested in other machine also]

The problem i am facing is When code set up in the server machine it is showing "Error creating ssl socket" Connection timed out.

Error appearing

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home/push.php on line 16
```

Any ideas?

Solutions found and tried

1. Opened the port 2195

Is it necessary to create a new ceritificate and all for hosting it in server?

EDIT

Push Code currently used

```
<?php 
 function sendApnsPushMessage($arrtokens,$req_message,$req_title) 
  {
    echo "Started APNS";
    if(count($arrtokens)>0)
    {
      $apnsCert = 'ck.pem';
      $apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
      $apnsPort = 2195;

      // Connect to Apple Push Notification server
      $streamContext = stream_context_create();
      stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
      stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '1234');
      //60 -> timeout in seconds
      $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 200, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);
      if (!$apns) 
      {
        echo($error);
        die('Error creating ssl socket');
      }
      stream_set_blocking ($apns, 0);
      echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

      for($i=0;$i<count($arrtokens);$i++)
      {
        $tokenid = $arrtokens[$i];
        echo($tokenid);
        $body['aps'] = array(
          'title' => $req_title,
          'alert' => $req_message,
          'sound' => 'default'
          );
        $payload = json_encode($body);
        $correctingToken=str_replace(' ', '', $tokenid);
        echo $correctingToken;
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $correctingToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $result = fwrite($apns, $msg, strlen($msg));
        if (!$result)
          echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        else
          echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
      }
      usleep(500000);
      fclose($apns);
    }
  }
$token= "dd3e343519524a986f946db0f888e895961b370720ee1c9b2495d0a58542607e";
$req_title='test';
$req_message='text';
$arrayOfTokens = array($token);
sendApnsPushMessage($arrayOfTokens,$req_message,$req_title);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you use wrong certificate to connect to sandbox APNS. You cannot use the same for sandbox and production. Also you eithr need to disable `RootCertificationAuthority` verification or set it properly to right CA -> [download Entrust's CA from here](https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_2048_ca.cer) and then do

```
$push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust.pem');
```

prior trying to connect to APNS:

```
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX, 'sandbox.pem');
$push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust.pem');

$msg = new ApnsPHP_Message($device_token);
$msg->setText('Hello');
...
$push->add($msg);

$push->connect();
$push->send();
$push->disconnect();
```

**EDIT** As you tagged this as `apns-php` I assumed you use APNSPHP lib to do the delivery, which I now see you do not so my answer is not really for your question - I will leave it anyway as it may help ones using APNS PHP (my example code is for it). I suggest you take a look: https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/ then and save yourself some time and burden.

Comment: Marcin Orlowski : Thanks for the quick response ..I added the code to the question.Can you please point me exactly where this LOC needs to be set? Sorry I am a complete beginner to serverside programming

Comment: I am trying to set up development enviornment in server.

Comment: I am not using ApnsPHP .I am just implementing the direct code .Please see the question

Comment: I noted and edited my answer. Why you do not use apns-php then?

Comment: ok I will give it a try. One more thing, to send to a set of device token is it possible with this?

Comment: sure, otherwise it would not make sense :) I edited my answer -> see the constructor for `ApnsPHP_Message`

Comment: Well I got the same issue in the server.Makes me think that some other thing is missing.Read about some entrust certificate.Hve any idea?